# How to run docker-compose at bootup?

Tags: 14.04, server, upstart, docker

This is on an Ubuntu 14.04 LTS VM running Docker and I suspect `respawn` is the cause of my problem but not sure of the ideal solution.

Current upstart script (`cat /etc/init/dockersuitecrm.conf`)

```
description "Start docker containers"
author "Batman"
start on filesystem and started docker
stop on runlevel [!2345]
respawn
script
    docker-compose -f /usr/bin/myapp/docker-compose.yml -p myapp start
end script
```

This 'works' in that `myapp` is alive and responsive but `/sbin/init` takes up all the CPU when I monitor with `htop`. If I remove the entry from upstart (`sudo rm /etc/init/dockersuitecrm.conf`) and manually SSH in and run `docker-compose -f /usr/bin/myapp/docker-compose.yml -p myapp start` I don't see the cpu at 100% issue and as before `myapp` is again alive and responsive.

So I suspect the way I'm starting docker-compose above is incorrect. What's the right way to start `docker-compose` is always running without manual intervention?

EDIT: Shouldn't matter but `/usr/bin/myapp -> /home/batman/dockerapps/myapp` as a symbolic link.

Comment: Not a solution but as a work-around, I'm able to run this without the `respawn` command in the script.

Comment: Same question, but I saw this: http://serverfault.com/questions/615820/start-and-stop-services-as-docker-containers. The magic is with using `docker-compose start`.

Comment: I have a similar config but don't use a `script` block.  Maybe that is part of the problem?  I have `chdir /usr/bin/myapp/` and on the next line `exec docker-compose up` instead.

Comment: Don't you just want to run docker-compose in the background? i.e. `docker-compose up -d`

Comment: put restart: always in the container spec

Answer (score 9):

Simply use crontab, instead of using a time intervall simply say @reboot

So login as the user who should start this script and type the command

```
crontab -e
```

and then enter

```
@reboot /better/enter/fullpath/here/docker-compose -f /usr/bin/myapp/docker-compose.yml -p myapp start
```

Reboot the system and see if it works. There's one advantage over upstart, even it it is started a little bit later, you don't have to worry much about dependcies like networking, etc. to be up already.

Comment: Any idea how clean a reboot would be running it this way?

Comment: Sorry, but this is not a very good answer. It might work from time to time, but as cron might be loaded before other docker requirements, you run into a race condition.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're using version 2 of Docker Compose definitions in you `docker-compose.yml`, you can do the following:

Defining `restart: always` like so:

```
version: '2'
services:
  web:
    image: nginx
    restart: always
```

**Reference:** https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/

Comment: The question is, which docker's site doesn't answer, was: "What's the right way to start docker-compose is always running without manual intervention?"

Answer (score 1):

Docker is not ready immediately
If you run the script too early, nothing will happen.
The docker will start responding to the docker ps command as soon as it is ready so you can use this trick in crontab:

nano /etc/crontabs/root

@reboot  /usr/bin/docker ps && /usr/bin/docker-compose -f /prod.yml start