# How to run a docker-compose as a systemd service?

Tags: systemd, services, docker

I found [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/612928/how-to-run-docker-compose-at-bootup), but that one uses cron - I'd like to use a systemd service instead. My `docker-compose.yml` is in `/home/me`, and I run it with `sudo docker compose up` (and just keep it running in the background with `tmux`), and stop it with `sudo docker compose down`.

While functional, I'd rather do this using a systemd service to start/stop my `docker-compose.yml` file.

How can I turn my `docker-compose.yml` file into a (working) systemd service?

Comment: I know this doesn't answer your question, but because google sends people here I thought I'd point out two things. `docker-compose` is now `docker compose` with a space. That and do you REALLY need to use `sudo` for your setup? If you can get away without using `sudo` you really should not use it.  The unit file would also need to be set to use a non-root user.

Comment: Have you tried using `containerd` to start containers at boot time? Ubuntu has it, this is one way to show that: `$ apt-cache search containerd | grep -v golang`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'll assume the docker-compose file is at `/home/cocomac/docker-compose.yml`, but you should replace it in my example with whatever the path to your docker compose file is.

First, let's create our service file. I like the text editor [micro](https://github.com/zyedidia/micro), personally, but feel free to use a different one. I'll call my service `docker-compose.service`, and it will be stored in `/etc/systemd/system`. Feel free to use a different name if you'd like, although if you do, remember to use that name when following the rest of this answer.

First, let's create and open the file with a text editor:

```
$ micro /etc/systemd/system/docker-compose.service
```

Put the following into the file:

```
[Unit]
Description=Some personal Docker containers
After=docker.service
Requires=docker.service

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c "docker compose -f /home/cocomac/docker-compose.yml up --detach"
ExecStop=/bin/bash -c "docker compose -f /home/cocomac/docker-compose.yml stop"

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

This gives our service a description, start + stop commands, as well as what it requires to be running before it starts. See [this Arch Wiki page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Systemd#Service_types) for an explanation of the different service types and what `RemainAfterExit` does.

Save the file and exit your text editor. You should now be able to do `sudo systemctl start docker-compose` to start your new systemd service. It may take a moment while it creates the containers, but once it finishes starting, you can do `sudo systemctl status docker-compose` to check the status of your service. You can also do `sudo systemctl stop docker-compose` to stop it (or `sudo systemctl enable docker-compose` to autostart it on boot)

Comment: Given that the container runs from a non-root home directory you probably want `[Service] ... User=cocomac`

Comment: Why not use `Type=forking`? Then `RemainAfterExit` should not be necessary.

Comment: Have you tried using `containerd` to start containers at boot time? Ubuntu has it, this is one way to show that: `$ apt-cache search containerd | grep -v golang`

Answer (score 2):

Using the following for the Service stanza also works & has the benefit that you can view logs using `journalctl -u docker-compose`:

```
[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c "docker-compose -f /home/cocomac/docker-compose.yml up"
ExecStop=/bin/bash -c "docker-compose -f /home/cocomac/docker-compose.yml stop"
```

Note that the `docker-compose` command does not include the `--detach` flag and you do not need the `RemainAfterExit` option. Note also that on the version of Ubuntu I tested this on (20.04), `docker-compose` is a separate command.

Answer (score 0):

If you [use `restart: always`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#restart) in your docker compose file (which is fairly typical), then the docker daemon will automatically restart the container when the daemon itself starts up -- which means that you don't need to use systemd to have it automatically running all the time.

You will still need to re-run `docker-compose` if you make changes to the compose file or to pull updates; this will not occur automatically.  But this does not require a systemd file.

Comment: [No](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#restart).  You linked to V3, though.

Answer (score 0):

You can also start `systemd` unit files listed in your user folder, and have them run on a regular basis. E.g. I have a certbot container that runs daily, to keep my ftp server's certificate up-to-date.

Based on the answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/859583/165224).

Set your user profile to 'linger', with `launchctl enable-linger ${USER}`.

Create `.service` and `.timer` unit files in `~/.config/systemd/user`. e.g.

`~/.config/systemd/user/certbot-ftp.service`

```ini
[Unit]
Description=Certbot LetsEncrypt renewal for vsftpd Server
                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=docker compose -f ~/docker-projects/ftp/compose.yaml restart certbot

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

`~/.config/systemd/user/certbot-ftp.timer`

```ini
[Unit]
Description=Run Certbot on a daily basis

[Timer]
OnCalendar=daily
Persistent=true

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
```

Then, to enable the service and associated timer, which will happen whether or not you're logged in (because login lingering has been enabled):

```sh
systemctl --user enable certbot-ftp --now
```